# Trace of a measure on a subset (or restriction of a measure to a subset)

Tags: measure-theory

This is an exercise from Measure Theory by Cohn. Given a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and subset $C$ which may *not* be measurable, we can form the trace of $\mathcal{A}$ on $C$ denoted $\mathcal{A}_C$ (a sigma algebra of sets $A\cap C$ where $A\in\mathcal{A}$). Now if we have a *finite* measure $\mu$ defined on $(X,\mathcal{A})$, we can define a measure on $\mathcal{A}_C$ as follows: there exists $C_1\in\mathcal{A}$, $C\subseteq C_1$ such that $\mu(C_1)=\mu^*(C):=\inf\{\mu(A):A\in\mathcal{A}, C\subseteq A\}$, and we can define $\mu_C(A\cap C)=\mu(A\cap C_1)$. We are asked to check

1. $\mu_C$ is well defined: (single-valued) if $A_1\cap C=A_2\cap C$ then $\mu(A_1\cap C_1)=\mu(A_2\cap C_1)$, and (independent of $C_1$) in fact $\mu_C(A\cap C)=\mu^*(A\cap C)$.
2. $\mu_C$ is a measure on $(C,\mathcal{A}_C)$, called the trace of $\mu$ on $C$.

If the subset $C$ is measurable, much of the difficulty of this exercise disappears. In trying to solve this exercise, I usually need to use the following property: if there exists $C_1\in\mathcal{A}$, $C\subseteq C_1$ such that $\mu(C_1)=\mu^*(C)$, then $\mu^*(C_1-C)=0$.

Is this property true in general? If yes, could you give me a hint? Also, if you have other approaches to this problem, please leave a hint in the comments as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See the solution at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374292/trace-sigma-algebra-and-measurable-envelope