# Outer measure and trace sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This question is from Donald Cohn measure theory textbook.

Let $\mu$ be a finite measure, and $\left(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu\right)$ a measurable space.$C \in X$ , $C_1 \in \mathcal{A},C\subseteq C_1$ with $\mu(C_1)=\mu^*(C)$. Show that if $A_1,A_2 \in \mathcal{A}$ are such that $A_1\cap C=A_2\cap C$ then $\mu(A_1\cap C_1)=\mu(A_2\cap C_1)$

I rewrite $A_1\cap C_1=(A_1\cap C) \cup (A_1\cap (C_1 - C))=(A_2\cap C) \cup (A_1\cap (C_1 - C))$.
Now the second term is such that $\mu^*(A_1\cap (C_1 - C))\leq \mu^*(C_1 - C) < \epsilon$, so that $\mu^*(A_1\cap C_1) = \mu^*(A_2\cap C)$

I can also rewrite $A_2\cap C_1=(A_2\cap C) \cup (A_2\cap (C_1 - C))$ and similarly in the end obtain $\mu^*(A_2\cap C_1) = \mu^*(A_2\cap C)$

We have then $\mu(A_1\cap C_1)=\mu^*(A_1\cap C_1) = \mu^*(A_2\cap C_1)=\mu(A_2\cap C_1)$ since the sets on the end sides of the equality are in $\mathcal{A}$ and then the measure and the outer measure agree (If I remember correctly)...

Now I am sure that this is vastly wrong, since I barely used any assumptions, so if you would be kind enough to point out where everything goes wrong , that would be much appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution went wrong at $\mu^*(C_1−C)<\epsilon$. In fact $\mu^*(C_1−C)$ can be as big as $\mu(X)$.

See [Trace $\sigma$-algebra and measurable envelope](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374292/trace-sigma-algebra-and-measurable-envelope)